# IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates general contract

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm sorry, yet another one of those questions, but I can simply not understand what is going on here, or where I'm going wrong.

**Overview:** I have a `ArrayList` containing multiple `Movie` - Objects.Those have a `date`, and a `startingTime`. I'd like to sort them by the following conditions, priority as listed:

- `date`
- `startingTime`

But when doing so, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:864)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:481)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:422)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:219)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2010)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1883)
    at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.MainActivity.sortByStartingTime(MainActivity.java:208)
```

**What I've got:**
I have the same thing going on in a JavaFX Project, but there I sort using `ArrayList.sort()` rather then `Collections.sort()`. I needed to convert to the `Collections.sort()` as apparently Android does not support the `ArrayList.sort()` Method yet.

This is the method that initiates the sorting and defines the `Comperator`:

```
private ArrayList<Movie> sortByStartingTime(ArrayList<Movie> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Movie>() { //This line is MainActivity.java: 208  ;)
        @Override
        public int compare(Movie o1, Movie o2) {
            int comparison = o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
            if (comparison == 0) {
                return o1.getStartingTime().compareTo(o2.getStartingTime());
            }
            return comparison;
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

As you can see, I compare the two `date` from the movies, and if they are equal, I continue to compare the starting times. 
Here are the two `compare()` Methods from my `DateKeeper`and `TimeKeeper` classes (I should maybe admit that they are self written):

```
public int compareTo(DateKeeper toCompare) {
    Calendar startDate = getAsCalendar();
    Calendar endDate = toCompare.getAsCalendar();
    long diff = endDate.getTimeInMillis() - startDate.getTimeInMillis();//in Milli seconds
    return (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

I am *not* returning either `-1`,`0` or `1` as I would like to use this method for the difference between two dates as well. I've read up on the `compare` method and found this should not be a problem.

```
public int compareTo(TimeKeeper toCompare) {
    int toReturn = Integer.compare(this.getValue(), toCompare.getValue());
    return toReturn;
}
```

`getValue()` simply returns what is known as `MINUTES_OF_DAY`.

**I don't understand how this violates the method contract. For what I know the `Comperator`is transitive (or is it not?) reflexive, and symmetric. So why am I getting this error message?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you divide by number of milliseconds in the day after you subtract.This may lead to two shows that may be <24 hours apart but on different days to show as on the same day.
Try:

```
public int compareTo(DateKeeper toCompare) {
    Calendar startDate = getAsCalendar();
    Calendar endDate = toCompare.getAsCalendar();
    long diff = (endDate.getTimeInMillis()/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) - (startDate.getTimeInMillis()/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));//in Milli seconds
    return (int) diff;
}
```

or set the time on both calendar objects to be midnight

Comment: Seems like it does the trick... But why? How does this change the general contract? Only your first solution works though... `getAsCalendar()` returns a `Calendar` on which `.set(year,month,day,0,0,0)` was called, where year, month, and day are all `Integers` in my `DateKeeper` object.

Comment: It does. Consider 3 times:
 a)9pm Tuesday,
 b)10 am Wednesday,
 c) 6am Thursday.
When you compare the first two... your comparator would say they're on the same day since they're less than 24 hrs apart... meaning 9pm Tuesday would come after 10 am Wednesday a > b. now comparing b and c would similarly give 10 am Wednesday is after 6am Thursday i.e. b>c... and a and c would say c>a.... the statements a>b, b>c, and c>a are not transitive...

Comment: just saw your comment about the calendar.. I can't think of why you'd have the issue then... but if it works then that's good i guess...